# How many trade offers can a villager have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After the Pretty Scary Update, the trade mechanics have changed: villagers can now have multiple trade offers after you increase your reputation with them.

This got me wondering how many trade offers a villager can have. I have done some brief research and watched some Pretty Scary Update video reviews, but haven't found anything on this topic.

I have tested it briefly in Creative Mode and so far I have got up to 9 trade offers from a single villager.

Have anyone already done conclusive tests for this in Survival Mode, or should I continue my experiments?

Comment: Have you tried testing in survival too? And how many villagers did you test with?

Comment: Nope, I have only did some testing on one villager on Creative Mode, I think the trading mechanism works the same in Creative and Survival, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, seeing as you have only tried with one villager, you should do this with multiple ones. To organize, you make want to put them in a hole that they cannot get out of, and order them by color robes, since there are a lot of variables to test.

Comment: That's the whole point of asking question here, because someone might have already done some thorough testing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The maximum number of [trade offers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading) you can get a villager to generate will depend on their profession. Each time you trade the last (right-most) offer a villager has, two changes happen to their available trade offers:

- Any trade offers that have been used enough times to deactivate them will be reactivated.
- There is a chance that a new trade offer will be added to the end of their list, which will be a different item than the trade offers currently appearing. If no new offer is added it usually means a previous offer was reoffered at a new exchange rate (e.g. 20 wheat for an emerald changing to 19 wheat).

Therefore, if you haven't traded the last offer to the point of deactivation *and* the villager hasn't yet shown you all of their trade offers, there is still a chance for them to generate more. A list of the possible trade offers by profession can be found [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#Possible_offers). If you add them all up, you get the following for the maximum number of different trade offers a given villager type can possibly make as of version 1.6.4:

- Farmer: 14
- Librarian: 9
- Priest: 13
- Blacksmith: 26
- Butcher: 11

And I can confirm this is true for the Librarian, because I maxed one out already. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no separate maximum, there is only the rule that there can't be two trades of the same type. You can see details of the possible trades here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading. It works out to:

- Butcher - 11
- Farmer - 14
- Blacksmith - 26
- Librarian - 9
- Priest - 13

So mostly what gnoive said, but with more accurate numbers.

Comment: I would have updated the existing answer instead of posting a new one that's essentially a dupe.

Comment: The correct count for farmers is 14, since you have to count shears and flint and steel separately (they are misleadingly placed on the same line in the image on the wiki). The librarian does now have 9 since enchanted books have been added as a trade offer since I posted my answer, so I updated that count.

Comment: @MBraedley I was trying to provide a simpler answer. There is no "maximum" per se, the only limit is that you can only have one of each trade.